# Basic Javascript Question

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm messing around with the Head First Javascript book. So my question is why doesn't the `if` clause in my function `turnSad()` trigger? **UPDATE** I've tried this in Chrome and FF4. Also, if I were to comment out the `if` statement, the function will work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function turnSad() {
        if (document.getElementById("rockImg").src == "rock_happy.png")
            document.getElementById("rockImg").src = "rock.png";
    }

    function touchRock() {
        var userName = prompt("What is your name?", "Enter your name here");

        if (userName) {
            alert("It is nice to meet you " + userName + ".");
            document.getElementById("rockImg").src = "rock_happy.png";
        }
        setTimeout("turnSad();", 1000);
    }

</script>
<img id="rockImg" src="rock.png" alt="iRock"  style="cursor:pointer" 
    onclick="touchRock();" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When accessing the `src` property (not the attribute), browsers may automatically resolve relative paths and give back the absolute path including the protocol, domain, port, etc.

To get or change the attribute value, use `getAttribute` and `setAttribute`.

```
image.getAttribute("src");

image.setAttribute("src", "someImage.png");
```

See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/anurag/4WyLZ/3).

Comment: This works but I don't fully understand your statement `When accessing the src property (not the attribute), browsers may automatically resolve relative paths and give back the absolute path including the protocol, domain, port, etc.` Do you mean behind the attribute `src` there are built in properties for it?

Comment: @Nai If the `src` attribute is set as `rock_happy.png` (which is a relative URL), and you get the value using `elem.src`, some browsers will automatically fill this up to be an absolute URL (ex. `http://yourdomain.com/rock_happy.png`).

Comment: The `src` property exists on the [DOM object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLImageElement) that represents an `<img>` in the HTML document. The `src` attribute on the other hand represents the raw value of the `src` attribute as it exists in the HTML document. When either getting or setting an attribute value, no logic is applied to that value and it is not transformed in any manner.

Answer (score 2):

@Anurag's answer is great, that's the best you can do, `getAttribute()` is supported by every browser that is around (being buggy in IE 5.5-7 but for getting `src` it works fine).

I just wanted to add a few things:

- Don't use `setTimeout()`'s string syntax, always pass in a function (you can pass in a closure to run more than one functions), which is considered best practice. The string variation works like `eval()`, the widely known evil bastard. So your code should look like (same applies to `setInterval`):

  ```
  setTimeout(turnSad, 1000);
  ```
- Othen than using `getAttribute()`, which is the best approach, you can also write a regex approach. I only add this for fun and broadening the view, please use @Anurag's solution.

  ```
  if (document.getElementById("rockImg").src.match(/(^|\/)rock_happy\.png$/i)) {
      document.getElementById("rockImg").src = "rock.png";
  }
  ```

  This will try to match in a case-insensitive way, looking for `rock_happy.png` in the end of the string, having either the beginning of the string or `/` before it.

  [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HLrbt/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Which browser are you using? IE might turn the filename into uppercase ("ROCK_HAPPY.PNG"). Use developer tools (press Refresh button in the tools toolbar) to determine what the real "src" attribute is, or just do `alert(document.getElementById().src)`

Comment: it's returning `rock_happy.png`